# Clearing Activity's instances in TabActivity

Tags: android

Here is a description of my problem:

I have got TabActivity consists of three tabs. Each tab binds with appropriate Activity. When I change data in one Activity this event should influences on another Activity's content. To implement this opportunity I use following flag:

***Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP***

This flag allows me to update content of Activity. But problem is that this creates a new Instance of Activity and doesn't free memory from previous.

There is a note in documentation that "you can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to come back to the created activity's instance" but when I use it in conjunction with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Activity's data doesn't update.

Does anybody know what method should help me to solve this problem and prevent me from memmory allocation.

Comment: In what method do you update your data? If it's `onCreate` than it won't be called since you don't create a new `Activity` but brings an existing one to front. `onNewIntent` will be called.

Comment: I understand it. I change data in non-TabActivity onCreate method, but if I have set Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP it brings to the top a new instance of Activity with updated data and doesn't delete the previous instance. This is my problem. How to delete the previous instance of activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a new `Activity`, use both flags and invoke your refresh in `onNewIntent`. Or you could rewrite your `TabActivity`'s tabs from `Activity`s to an ordinary `View`s

Comment: In what Activity should I call onNewIntent?

Comment: So if I change data in code of one simple Activity how can I call onNewIntent method in the second Activity?

Comment: `onNewIntent` will be called by the system when there will be a start intent of an `Activity` that was already in the stack, i.e. when you will start an intent with 2 flags that you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have understood. I.e I should `override onNewIntent()` in my changable content Activity. Thank you so much for your respond. One more vote)))))))